# Removing logback configuration changes that were made programmatically

Tags: java, log4j, logback, slf4j

I have all the default configuration in `logback.xml` file. The only logger that exists in the .xml file is root logger.
In my application I've changed the level of my class logger programmatically by doing this:

```
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChangeLoggingConfigurationAction.class);

logger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Now the logger for this specific class will only log error messages. I've made such changes to a lot of other classes as well. Now I want to reset all these changes to the default level as it was in the start.

Is it possible to do it programmatically without having to change the level of the logger of each class, by simply discarding all the changes I made programmatically?